# discord.py/nextcord.py Reaction role with on_raw_reaction_add not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I´ve been a long time trying to figure out why this isn´t working, the part that doesn´t work is where I get the role, but I can´t figure out why.

Does anyone know? :c

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message_id = 999984925216358470

  if message_id == payload.message_id:
    user = payload.member
    guild_user = user.guild
    emoji = payload.emoji.name


    if emoji == "<:hi:999730650087165993>":
      role = nextcord.utils.get(guild_user.guild.roles, name="the role")
      print(role)
      await user.add_roles(role)

  else:
    print("Not a reaction roles message")
```

Comment: Can you please describe what it means that it doesn't work? What do you expect, and what is happening that you didn't expect? If you have an error please show the full error-message as well.

Comment: There is no error, I have debugged the code and everything works except the part where I get the role, it doesn´t get anything, which is strange beacause I have other part where I get another role exactly the same way and it works just fine.

Comment: So your specific problem then is, that the call to `nextcord.utils.get(guild_user.guild.roles, name="the role")` should return a role-object, but it returns `None` instead, is that right?

Comment: The `print(role)` doesn´t return anything, no text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this library, but looking at the [documentation](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html) tells me that the `nextcord.utils.get`-function does the following:

> A helper that returns the first element in the iterable that meets all the traits passed in attrs

> If nothing is found that matches the attributes passed, then None is returned.

I suppose, that there is no element in the iterable that meets the trait `name="the role"`. There could be many reasons for this, maybe you can find out if you take a look at the iterable `guild_user.guild.roles` by printing that, or better yet using a debugger.

Comment: Thanks! looks like using the `guild_user` variable wasn´t working so I just used `role = nextcord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name="Notificaciones")`

I will debug more things in the future